# selenium cssselector in c# for kendo widget

Tags: c#, selenium, css-selectors

I am having a hard time understanding CssSelector for an onscreen object I am trying to find (and others that are just like it). Give

```
<TH class=k-header id=c9a12c99-612c-4405-9b3d-fd551d03a10c role=columnheader rowSpan=1 jQuery111106564522723473856="19" data-role="columnsorter" data-index="0" data-title="SEQ" data-field="SequenceDays"><A tabIndex=-1 class=k-link href="#">SEQ</A></TH>
```

I want to identify this object by the  tag and the data-title or data-field attribute.

Is anyone able to show me how to do this? C# would be preferable, but Java is ok too.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [CSS selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). I use it on a regular basis. MDN has some really good [explanations and examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors). There a a TON of other tutorials and what not on the web also. I highly recommend learning CSS selectors. They are very powerful and fast compared to XPath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java:
Tag + data title:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("th.k-header[data-title='SEQ']"));
```

Tag + data field:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("th.k-header[data-field='SequenceDays']"));
```